# remove duplicate rows in R based on values in all columns

Tags: r, duplicates, unique

I have the following dataset
`col1 col2 col3`
`a     b    1`
`a     b    2`
`a     b    3`

`unique(dataset)` returns
`col1 col2 col3`
`a     b     1`

`dataset[!duplicated(1:3),]` returns
`col1 col2 col3`
`a     b    1`
`a     b    2`
`a     b    3`

But the same thing fails to work in following
dataset2
`col1 col2 col3`
`a     b    1`
`a     b    1`

`unique(dataset2)` returns
`col1 col2 col3`
`a     b    1`

`dataset2[!duplicated(1:3),]` returns
`col1 col2 col3`
`a     b    1`
`a     b    1`
`NA    NA   NA`

Comment: `!duplicated(1:3)` is not what you needed.  `!duplicated(dataset)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `!duplicated`:

```
dataset[!duplicated(dataset[c("col1", "col2", "col3")]),]
```